# User to choose what goes into their subscription on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, subscriptions

I'm looking to build a website using woocommerce where the user subscribes to a monthly subscription but chooses what goes into their box - a bit like graze.com where you can tell them the 'snacks you fancy'.

I've looked into woocommerce subscriptions add on which sorts out the subscription issue however I don't know how to let the user choose what snacks they want before paying for the subscription.

Plan:

1. user clicks 'buy subscription'
2. page comes up with 'first choose 12 of your favourite DVD's'
3. after they have been selected, user clicks continue and gets taken to payment page.
4. they pay and subscription is set up.

On the back end, I should be able to see what the user has chosen as their preferred DVD's and preferably be able to cross off once each of the DVD's have been sent.

I spoke to woo commerce and they said this is possible but it will have to be a custom coded feature. If anyone could point me into the right direction on how I should set this up, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

ps. if there is another wordpress way of doing this, i'm happy to look into that also.

Comment: you need a programmer...

Comment: Reigel - I wasn't looking for someone to state the obvious here. I was looking for someone to suggest to me how to add in what I need.